# Why can't I extend the Fixnum class in a module and use it?

Tags: ruby, class, module, extend

I've created a module in which I extend the Fixnum class with a new method. But when I `require` the module and try to use the extended method, it returns:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `roundup' for 13:Fixnum
```

Here's what my module looks like:

```
module EanControl
  # Extend Fixnum with #roundup
  class Fixnum
    def self.roundup
      return self if self % 10 == 0   # already a factor of 10
      return self + 10 - (self % 10)  # go to nearest factor 10
    end
  end

  # More code...
end
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
require 'path_to_module'
12.roundup

# => NoMethodError: undefined method `roundup' for 13:Fixnum
```

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are three problems with your code:

1. You are creating a *new* class `EanControl::Fixnum`, but you actually want to change the *existing* builtin `::Fixnum`. Solution: explicitly start the constant lookup from the top-level, or, more idiomatically, just drop the module.

   ```
   module EanControl
     class ::Fixnum
       # …
     end
   end

   # although it would be much simpler to just do this:

   class Fixnum
     # …
   end
   ```
2. You define `roundup` as a singleton method of the object `Fixnum`, but you call it as an instance method of instances of `Fixnum`. Solution: make `roundup` an instance method:

   ```
   class Fixnum
     def roundup
       return self if (self % 10).zero? # already a factor of 10
       self + 10 - (self % 10)          # go to nearest factor 10
     end
   end
   ```
3. The Ruby Language Specification does not actually guarantee that there even *is* a `Fixnum` class. It only guarantees that there is an `Integer` class, and it allows that different implementations may provide implementation-specific subclasses. (E.g. YARV has `Fixnum` and `Bignum` subclasses of `Integer`.) Since you only add the method to `Fixnum`, it won't work for other `Integer`s, which aren't `Fixnum`s. And since the range of `Fixnum`s is different for different implementations of architectures (e.g. on YARV on 32 bit systems, `Fixnum`s are 31 bit, on 64 bit systems, they are 63 bit, on JRuby, they are always 64 bit), you don't even know for sure what numbers your method will work on and when it will fail. (E.g.: `9223372036854775808.roundup # NoMethodError: undefined method 'roundup' for 9223372036854775808:Bignum`.) Solution: make the method an instance method of `Integer`:

   ```
   class Integer
     def roundup
       return self if (self % 10).zero? # already a factor of 10
       self + 10 - (self % 10)          # go to nearest factor 10
     end
   end
   ```

Lastly, I want to suggest at least using a mixin here:

```
module IntegerWithRoundup
  def roundup
    return self if (self % 10).zero? # already a factor of 10
    self + 10 - (self % 10)          # go to nearest factor 10
  end
end

class Integer
  include IntegerWithRoundup
end
```

Now, if someone else debugs your code, and wonders where this `roundup` method comes from, there is a clear trace in the ancestry chain:

```
12.method(:roundup).owner
# => IntegerWithRoundup
```

Even better would be to use a Refinement, that way your monkeypatch doesn't pollute the global namespace:

```
module IntegerWithRoundup
  module Roundup
    def roundup
      return self if (self % 10).zero? # already a factor of 10
      self + 10 - (self % 10)          # go to nearest factor 10
    end
  end

  refine Integer do
    include Roundup
  end
end

12.roundup
# NoMethodError: undefined method `roundup' for 12:Fixnum

using IntegerWithRoundup

12.roundup
# => 20
```

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic anwser.

Answer (score 1):

In your extension, you have defined `roundup` as a **class** method while `12` is an **instance**.

Try:

```
module EanControl
  # Extend Fixnum with #roundup
  class Fixnum
    def roundup
      return self if self % 10 == 0   # already a factor of 10
      return self + 10 - (self % 10)  # go to nearest factor 10
    end
  end

  # More code...
end
```

Comment: This won't work either, since now it is still an instance method of `EanControl::Fixnum`, not `::Fixnum`.